# How to use「足がすくんだ」

Tags: expressions, phrases

I want to say "The building was very high, so I froze with fear". Would I be right to say:

> 「建物がとても高くて僕は足がすくんだ」

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「建物{たてもの}がとても高{たか}くて僕{ぼく}は**足{あし}がすくんだ**。」

is a perfectly natural-sounding sentence (with excellent particle choices).  Your use of 「足がすくむ」 is just very appropriate here.

Colloquially, young people might go with 「ビビりまくる」 or 「ビビる」 instead of 「足がすくむ」 in that situation.

I myself would try to sound funny (and probably fail) by saying 「足が**む**くんだ。」 or 「足が**む**くんじゃった」 by using 「**む**くむ」 instead of the correct verb 「**す**くむ」.  That means "My feet are swollen."